# Curry howard equivalence on an equality

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus, type-theory

Surely $x=2$ is a $Proposition$. If so, then under the correspondence of propositions as types, the above proposition has a type. Which type is it?

Additionally, under the correspondence of proofs as terms, I should also see some $\lambda-term$ as a proof of the above proposition. Can you give an example?

I was thinking the type would be $Eq(x,2,Nat)$, the equality type with terms $x$ and $2$ and type $Nat$? On the other hand, the proposition may be an assignment $x:=2$ rather than an equality. Does that change the type? Because then I would immediately think of $\lambda$-binding so the proposition would look like $\lambda x.2$. Or is that entirely unrelated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Curry-Howard correspondence works best for *propositional logic*, in which we don't consider any internal structure of atomic propositions. In other words, the formulas being considered contain only *propositional variables* (which can take the values "true" or "false") and logical connectives.

"$x=2$" belongs not to propositional logic, but to *first-order logic*, where we have variables that stand for individual mathematical objects (such as numbers) and predicates (such as $=$) that express relations between these objects.

Under the Curry-Howard correspondence, first order logic usually becomes a lambda calculus with *dependent types*, and things are a good deal more complicated than with the simply typed lambda calculus that works for propositional logic.

But that's not the end of your trouble here. Because $x=2$ is *not always true* (or at least it's not necessarily true if the universe we're speaking about contains numbers other than $2$), you have better **not be able to prove it**.

And since there *is no proof* of $x=2$, it is futile to look for a lambda term that would encode such a hypothetical proof.